# Puppet: Requiring packages based on parameter

Tags: puppet

Very new to puppet here.

Suppose:

```
define add_user ($shell) {
    $username = $title
    user { $username:
        shell = $shell,
    }
    group { $username:
        require => User[$username]
    }
}
```

And:

```
class zsh {
    package { 'zsh': ensure => 'installed' }
}

class bash {
    package { 'bash': ensure => 'installed' }
}
```

And finally:

```
node default {
    add_user { 'foo':
        shell => '/bin/zsh'
    }
}
```

How do I set up a requirement from the user to the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add something like this to your add_user function:

```
define add_user ($shell) {
  case $shell {
      '/bin/zsh':          { include zsh }
      '/bin/bash':         { include bash  }
      default:             { fail('Unknown Shell') }
  }
...
}
```